# The requested resource is not available Glassfish 4

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, glassfish

I have recently started working on web applications and was trying to set up a practise project to try out different things. But I am stuck at a very initial stage and I googled a lot but could not find the solution to my problem. I have associated the project with an EAR project and the ear is deployed on the server.

This is the project setup I am facing problems with :

web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
        <display-name>College Administration</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>kumar.suraj.college.administration.login.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>
```

application.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" id="Application_ID"   version="7">
  <display-name>web-college-administrationEar</display-name>
  <module>
       <web>
           <web-uri>web-college-administration.war</web-uri>
           <context-root>web-college-administration</context-root>
       </web>
  </module>
  </application>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish  Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish- web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
 <glassfish-web-app>
      <context-root>web-college-administration</context-root>
 </glassfish-web-app>
```

login.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
         <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" action="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
             <label for="usermail  ">Email</label> 
             <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>
             <br/> 
             <label for="password  ">Password</label> 
             <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required> 
             <br/>      
             <input type="submit" value="Login">
         </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package kumar.suraj.college.administration.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
*/
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    response.getWriter().append("Hello Suraj");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.doGet(request, response);
  }

}
```

The login.jsp is placed in WebContent/WEB-INF folder of my project.

When I hit the url http://localhost:53809/web-college-administration/login

I get the following out put "Served at: /web-college-administrationHello Suraj" as per the doGet method of LoginServlet.java.

But when I hit the url http://localhost:53809/web-college-administration/login.jsp I get the following error :

```
   HTTP STATUS 404 - NOT FOUND
   type status report
   message Not Found
   description The requested resource is not available.
```

And in eclipse console I get the following message :

```
   2016-07-03T16:34:18.969+0530|Severe: PWC6117: File "null" not found.
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my setup ?

Comment: Could you please post the directory structure of your project?

Comment: 404 status code is for resource which is not available.

Comment: Hi @RomanC do you see any incorrect information in my answer?

Comment: @SanjeevSaha I didn't see it.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha It is not nice of you to ask me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The login.jsp is placed in WebContent/WEB-INF folder of my project.

Could you please put `login.jsp` in `WebContent` folder of your project in eclipse then clean the project and try the URL: http://localhost:53809/web-college-administration/login.jsp again?

Comment: @SanjeevSaha yes it worked,I was just trying what you said so it took time in replying. Thank you very much for your support. Also if its convenient for you could you please provide me if you know any good links or tutorials explaining the directory structure of web projects both war/ear and maven and non maven

Comment: also which resource should be placed where as I have seen in some cases jsp files being placed in web-inf folders. also it is good practise to keep resources that are private to your application in web-inf folders as they cant be accessed publicly.

Comment: @SurajKumar you will find many good tutorials at: http://www.mkyong.com/